# Error in converting a column type in Dataset into datetime type with specific format in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I have a dataset and I want to change the format of a column named "Last Updated".

```
 DB['Last Updated'].head()

 0     January 7, 2018
 1    January 15, 2018
 2      August 1, 2018
 3        June 8, 2018
 4       June 20, 2018
Name: Last Updated, dtype: object
```

I want to make the format like 7/1/2018, so I wrote the following in python.

```
 DB['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(DB['Last Updated'],format= '%d/%m/%Y')
```

But this error appears:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
 302             try:
 --> 303                 values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
304                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-62-1dd2ca5f727a> in <module>()
 ----> 1 DB['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(DB['Last Updated'],format= '%d/%m/%Y')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin)
371     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
372         from pandas import Series
--> 373         values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
374         result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
375     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, MutableMapping)):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
304                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
305             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 306                 raise e
307 
308     if arg is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
271                     try:
272                         result = array_strptime(arg, format, exact=exact,
--> 273                                                 errors=errors)
274                     except tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime:
275                         if errors == 'raise':

pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

 ValueError: time data 'January 7, 2018' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)
```

How can I handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `format` argument in `pd.to_datetime(...)` is used to specify the format of the string you are converting from (not to specify an output format). In order to convert your date strings to datetime objects and then to a specific output format, you can do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'Last Updated': 'January 7, 2018'}, {'Last Updated': 'January 15, 2018'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last Updated'])
df['Last Updated'] = df['Last Updated'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)
# OUTPUT
#   Last Updated
# 0   07/01/2018
# 1   15/01/2018
```

Comment: data_google['Last Updated']= pd.to_datetime(data_google['Last Updated'])                           
---> data_google['Last Updated']= data_google['Last Updated'].dt.striftime('%d/%m/%Y')
--> ValueError: day is out of range for month                                   - ->and when make ..--> data_google['Last Updated']= pd.to_datetime(data_google['Last Updated'],dayfirst = True)
--> data_google['Last Updated']= data_google['Last Updated'].dt.striftime('%d/%m/%Y')  ,,--> i got this error ValueError: month must be in 1..12

Comment: Sounds like you may have some date strings in your column that `pd.to_datetime()` can't handle. If you can share some other examples of the different date strings in your column, we may be able to help.

Comment: I found this field 2.3.16 >.. Does it effect??

Comment: @AFB - if one of the "Last Updated" column values is "2.3.16", then `pd.to_datetime` should handle it just fine. But if you mean that one of the "Last Updated" column values is "2.3.16 >", then `pd.to_datetime` will raise a ValueError. If your "Last Updated" column values are not all ordinary date strings (such as the ones you posted in your question), then you will need to write a custom method to reformat them rather than using `pd.to_datetime` along with `datetime.strftime` in the way outlined in this answer.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do that..Thanks